# Magento associated products doesn't work

Tags: magento

I have Magento 1.6

I have done a bulk upload today, (all products are configurable) and they have created normally except they didn't associate.
I can't figure out why, I have tried to change the attribute, but it still not working.
I have deleted them all and start again, and when I click on the configurable product, it is now asking me to select a super attribute, so I need to click on it, associate manually the product, then it is working.

I suppose it is coming from my set up in the attribute ? but I can't figure out what

Hope you can  help

Comment: Stupid question: Did you reindex everything?

Comment: thanks for the reply. Yes I have reindex the date

Comment: When I click on the configurable product I have this message "Only attributes with scope "Global", input type "Dropdown" and Use To Create Configurable Product "Yes" are available." then I click on the attribute, then I can manually associate the product.